# Complicated gridview binding in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview

I have the following tables:
Products:

```
| ID | SerialNumber | Name |
```

ProductsData:

```
| ID | ProductID | Date | Value |
```

I want to create a gridview in ASP.Net that will shows each product in a line:

```
| Name | Serial Number | Last date data | the value at the date |  Maximum value in the last 10 days |
```

I appreciate if anyone can help using Linq ?
Or maybe creating a view ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to write an sql query?

Comment: I am not so familiar with SQL queries. I will appreciate if you can help me with that. maybe to create a view

Comment: How do you imagine creat a view without know sql? Please start reading a book about SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Learn SQL first, before going towards LINQ or EF. Anyways here, you need joins to achieve your result. Below is a sample Join sql. Google to learn more or see the image below.[image: enter code here]

Sample Query.

### Employee

Id, EmployeeName, DeptId, Salary, Address

### Department

Id,Name, HOD

Query to find Employee with their dept name

```
Select E.EmployeeName, D.Name 
From Employee E 
inner join Department D on E.DeptId= D.Id
```

Similarly You can use Left Joins and Rights . See the image and know its usage. For more google.

Answer (score 0):

Its depend on what you are using here?

SqlHelper>

You can create a stored procedure where you can write your sql query using Sql Join and then you can bind your gridview via this stored procedure.

Entity Collection>

You can get the results like this using join in lambda.

Hope this is what which you want to integrate .